# How will I hold and drag the image while it is moving?

Tags: ios, xcode

Here is my code in moving the image randomly and for the touch code.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(randomizeXandY) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)randomizeXandY {

CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width);
CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.height);

[self moveObjectsAtX:x Y:y];

}

-(void)moveObjectsAtX:(CGFloat)x Y:(CGFloat)y {

[UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
    imgView.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
}];

}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

  if ([touch view] == imgView) {

      imgView.center = touchLocation;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code in touchesBegin and touchesEnded

```
-(void)touchesBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 // stop timers here

}   

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 // start timers here again

}
```

Comment: how will i stop it? i tried to invalidate the timer when touches began but it still doesnt work

Comment: Use a flag to check if you can move the image view and change flag's value inside touch handling code.

Comment: how to start the timer again in touches ended?

Comment: You can use fire.  [timer fire]

Comment: what seems to be the problem here @SamkitJain?

Comment: @TomaszBąk How to change flags value?

Comment: You can make a BOOL varibale inside timer function and make that BOOL yes and no in touchBegin and based on that only call [self moveObjectsAtX:x Y:y];
otherwise dont call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use these methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

   //...
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    //..

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

   //...
}
```

in touchesBegan method, check if the touch is on your image:

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(yourImage.frame, touchLocation)){
    dragging = YES;
}
```

if it yes set a global variable, for example bool dragging to YES.

in touchesMoved:

check

```
if (dragging){
   yourImage.frame = CGRectMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y,yourImage.frame.size.widht,yourImage.frame.size.height);
}
```

in touchesEnded:
set dragging to NO

dragging = NO;

So :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(yourImage.frame, touchLocation)){
        dragging = YES;
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
    //...
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (dragging){
        yourImage.frame = CGRectMake(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y,yourImage.frame.size.widht,yourImage.frame.size.height);
    }
    //..

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    dragging = NO;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. In it's handling method you can check possible states of the touch.

```
 -(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
      switch (recognizer.state) {
           case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
                CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

                ...

                break;
           }

           case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:

                ...

                break;

           case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:

                ...

                break;

           default:
                break;
}
```